# Hibernate Join Mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, hql, inner-join

I have two db tables:

TARGET_TABLE (composite key on USER_ID and TARGET_ID)

```
USER_ID | TICKET_NO | TARGET_USER
---------------------------------
 A11    |  12345    |  A22
 A11    |  12346    |  A33 
 A44    |  12347    |  A55
```

USER_DETAILS_TABLE

```
CORP_ID | USER_NAME
------------------
 A11    | Steve
 A22    | Jon
 A33    | Paul
 A44    | Dave
 A55    | James
```

I want to be able to join these tables when I'm using select statements only.

For example I would like to do:

```
Select USER_ID, USER_NAME, TICKET_NO FROM TARGET_TABLE INNER JOIN USER_DETAILS ON TARGET_TABLE.USER_ID = USER_DETAILS_TABLE.CORP_ID
```

I can't seem to find the best way to do this. I have looked at the Hibernate examples for mapping but these are examples on how to write to both tables I simply want to get a user name from a table I can't touch!

I currently have two separate mappings for each table and run a separate query to get the user name but this doesn't seem like the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This HQL would work `select tt.userId, tt.ticketNo, u.userName from TargetTable tt, User u where tt.userId = u.corpId`.

However, this would return a `List<Object[]>` where each list element represents one row with 3 columns. You could extract these manually, or for example have some `my.package.UserVO` object with constructor `public UserVO(String userId, String ticketNo, String userName) { ... }`. In that case, this

```
session.createQuery("select new my.package.UserVO(tt.userId, tt.ticketNo, u.userName) from TargetTable tt, User u where tt.userId = u.corpId", UserVO.class).list()
```

would return instances of `UserVO`.